# jquery wrap more than one element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to wrap an element with the following code:

```
$('.sltxt').wrap('<div class="wrapCheck"><input type="checkbox"><div class="chkbox"></div></div>');
```

I am getting this:

```
<div class="wrapCheck">
    <input type="checkbox">
        <div class="sltxt">
            text
        </div>
    </input>
    <div class="chkbox"></div>
</div>
```

However, I would like the code to be wrapped like this:

```
<div class="wrapCheck">
  <input type="checkbox">
    <div class="chkbox">
    </div>
<div class="sltxt">test</div>
</div>
```

is there any way to make this happen? (also input adds an unwanted `</input>`)

edit: upon further inspection, I actually need the following code:

```
<li>
     <a href="#drop2"><span class="pk-add_small"></span></a>
     <div class="wrapCheck">
         <input type="checkbox">
         <div class="chkbox"></div>
         <span class="sltxt">Κεντρική Κατηγορία 2</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

and I have this code:

```
<li>
   <a href="#drop2"><span class="pk-add_small"></span></a>
   <input type="checkbox">
   <span class="sltxt">Κεντρική Κατηγορία 2</span>
</li>
```

Comment: That's not how it works, unfortunately. You can wrap a structure around an element, but for elements that aren't wrapping, you'll have to just insert them in the appropriate place with append() or prepend().

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for this... first wrap in the outer element, then add the other elements:

```
$('.sltxt')
    .wrap('<div class="wrapCheck"></div>')
    .before('<input type="checkbox" /><div class="chkbox"></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pmLdz/

Comment: ..is there a way to add a variable id in the checkbox here? Alternatively, is there a way to add just an open <div> or a closed </div> seperately?

Comment: If I understand the question, you can just concatenate the string: `'<input type="checkbox" id="' + myId + '" />'`

Comment: I mix up syntax when switching between languages sometimes too.

Comment: sorry to bother again, but is there a way to keep the input out of the wrap? is there a way to keep the structure I am looking for by wrapping or inserting code around the input AND .sltxt?

Comment: I'm sure there is, using some combination of `wrap`, `wrapAll`, `prepend`, `append`, `before`, and `after` in the right order. You may want to look at `wrapAll` in particular, it lets you wrap multiple elements inside a container together instead of individually.

Comment: I've been trying for the last hour to do so, and I am so p**** I can't even think straight, so I thought someone with some more experience might help before I bring my whole house down. :/

Comment: I would use wrapall, but I want to avoid adding extra classes. wrapInner is also out of the question because theres another element inside the parent

Comment: Edit your post with the html you want to end up with.

Comment: updated. thanks for your efforts in advance. You have already helped me much

Comment: To convert the second new snippet to the first, this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/BCUNm/. Let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: Note that I had to close the `input` tag. It should be self-closing, meaning ending with `/>`

Comment: although it looks like it's working in the fiddle, it disappears on my code... UGHH.. thanks though, will look into it

Comment: Does your code stop up until the <li> or does it go further up to the parents? edit: in my code it removes both the input and the .sltxt element

Comment: It shouldn't go up to parents at all, it should just take siblings except for the `<a>`. What do you mean it removes the elements? Like from the DOM? Can you post a fiddle that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: yes, it removes them from the dom. I wish I could post my code, it's too complex and too large to post. I can tell you though that using your code removes input and .sltxt from the dom

Comment: Do you by chance have more than one `.sltxt` element? If so, the elements are probably being moved.. try this: http://jsfiddle.net/Wc3p4/

Comment: now this one seems to be working ok, but breaks my design, have to look thorougly what it breaks

Comment: oops! no! my bad, I forgot to delete a </div> that was messing my design. I think this works! :) Let me check more thoroughly!

Comment: FINALLY! :) You are my hero (for today!) :) May you have a happy new year.. and only after... 5 hours (!!) I have it working as it should! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sltxt').wrap('<div class="wrapCheck">')
    .parent() // traverse up to .wrapCheck then prepend the input
    .prepend('<div class="chkbox"><input type="checkbox"/></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nZdMD/